# Symfony 3.2.2 FOSUserBundle Authenticate user listener not trigger

Tags: php, listener, symfony

I know this question has already been posted, and i did tried some if not all the answers I found, but without success yet, therefore here's my question:

I just installed a new Symfony application and successfully installed FOSUserBundle, made a few modification on the UserEntity, and on the FormRegistrationType (added some fields,...)

Then, I tried to follow this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

Here's my services.yml:

```
app.suscriber.authentification:
        class: MyBundle\Suscriber\AuthSubscriber
        arguments: [ "@doctrine" ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event.suscriber }
```

And here's my AuthSuscriber class =>

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Suscriber;

use MyBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class AuthSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event, $eventName, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
     dump('here, but not seen at any time');die();
     }
   }
```

I do see my service with the console:

```
php bin/console debug:container app.suscriber.authentification
```

output => 
[image]

But the following command line does not show my subscriber in any way =>

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher | grep "fos_user.registration" -A10
```

With the following output =>

[image]

Even though it shows the AuthentificationListener from FOS\UserBundle...

If anyone could give me an hint on how to debug this kind of bug I would gladly listen to him, cause I'm completely lost here >____<"

Thanks,

Hurin

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see the relevant output from the commands you posted

Comment: So when confirming a user, this code isn't called ?

Comment: When i register a user, this code isn't called, even if i see that in the vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php, line 71, there's this line => 
`code`
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

i would really love to understand how the services.yml is read, cause i dig into the code, to see that the dispatch called is in fact generated ( imho) and located in the var/cache/dev/classes.php, and here, when i look at the listeners, i see no trace of my AuthentificationSuscriber >___<"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a typo in the tag name? Underscore **_** instead of **.**

```
app.suscriber.authentification:
    class: MyBundle\Suscriber\AuthSubscriber
    arguments: [ "@doctrine" ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

[The event list](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-event-subscriber).

Comment: Thank you very much COil, i know it must sounds stupid, but yes that was it a simple typo >___>"

Is there any way to found out easily if i made a typo in my tags ?

Anyway, thank you very much COil, that was very nice of you to give me a hand :)

Have a nice day, and sorry for the time losts on my typo problem o/

Comment: You're welcome. I think there is no way to control tags because you can define your own ones.

Comment: Ok, i understand better now, i do still have a lot to learn before "mastering" symfony, anyway thanks for your time, have a nice day